# How can i make invisible the clusters without cluster centroid in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-science, data-mining

I have a kmeans clustered object with 15 clusters. I rearranged the cluster_centers of the object and removed 5 specific cluster centers form that list. Now i want to visiulize my object and cluster centers. But i couldn't find a way to make some clusters invisible.

My originally clustered data is :

[image]

When i try to visualize my kmeans data object with its new cluster centroids i get this output:
[image]

I want to make invisible the clusters without "X" markers on it. How can i do that?

I used this code to plot the above:

```
plt.scatter(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1],c=TrainData[1],cmap='gist_rainbow')
plt.scatter(new_centroids[:,0], new_centroids[:, 1],s = 150, c = 'black', label = 'Centroid', marker="x")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a filter to exclude the undesired values.
You need to convert your `TrainData[1]` to a numpy array (if it isn't already), using `np.array(TrainData[1])`.

Here is an example using sklearns `KMeans`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.normal(size=(5000, 2))
kmeans_result = KMeans(n_clusters=15).fit(X_train)
new_centroids = kmeans_result.cluster_centers_
cluster_ids = kmeans_result.labels_
# cluster_ids = np.array(TrainData[1])

undesired1 = 3
undesired2 = 5
undesired3 = 7
filter = (cluster_ids != undesired1) & (cluster_ids != undesired2) & (cluster_ids != undesired3)
plt.scatter(X_train[filter, 0], X_train[filter, 1], c=cluster_ids[filter], cmap='gist_rainbow', alpha=0.4)
desired_centroid_ids = np.array([i for i in range(len(new_centroids)) if i not in [undesired1, undesired2, undesired3]])
plt.scatter(new_centroids[desired_centroid_ids, 0], new_centroids[desired_centroid_ids, 1], s=150, c='black',
            label='Centroid', marker="x")
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried the code but it gives an error `tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: What is the type of `TrainData`?  Can you convert it to a numpy array?

Comment: `df = make_blobs(n_samples=5000, n_features=15,centers=15, cluster_std=1,random_state=10)` i defined Data using that code and split it into training and testing.

Comment: You probably can use `TrainData[1][filter]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i am trying to scatter centroids in my centroid list i created earlier but they showing up in irrelevant places. Why it is like that?

Comment: That was exactly what i meant, no edits necessary, Thank you so much for your efforts!!